# A normal subgroup is the union of conjugacy classes.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups

This is Exercise 2.6.5 of F. M. Goodman's *"Algebra: Abstract and Concrete"*. I want to check my proof.

> **Exercise 2.6.5:** Show that a subgroup (of a group) is normal if and only if it is the union of conjugacy classes.

### My Attempt:

Let $N$ be a subgroup of a group $G$. Then

$$\begin{align}
N\text{ is normal }&\Leftrightarrow \forall g\in G, N=gNg^{-1} \\
&\Leftrightarrow \forall n\in N \forall g\in G\exists m_{n, g}\in N, n=gm_{n, g}g^{-1} \tag{1}\\
&\Leftrightarrow N=\bigcup_{n\in N}\underbrace{\bigcup_{g\in G}\left\{gm_{n, g}g^{-1}\right\}}_{\text{conjugacy class of }n}\tag{2} \\
&\Leftrightarrow N=\bigcup_{n\in N}[n],
\end{align}$$ where $[n]$ is the conjugacy class of $n$.$\square$

> Is this proof valid?

### Thoughts:

I hope to make $(1)$ to $(2)$ (and back) more explicit.

Please help :)

Comment: It would be a better proof if it consisted of English sentences rather than just a wall of symbols.

Comment: @HenningMakholm True.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I wanted to use "if and only if" statements all the way. Presenting it like this seemed most efficient.

Comment: @Shaun sir ,very interesting  question.

Comment: Thank you, @LostinSpace.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If $N$ is a normal subgroup of group $G$ and $n\in N$ then $gng^{-1}\in N$ for every $g\in G$ or equivalently $[n]\subseteq N$ where $[n]:=\{gng^{-1}\mid g\in G\}$ is the conjugacy class of $n$.

This tells us that: $$N=\bigcup_{n\in N}[n]$$
If conversely $N$ is a subgroup of group $G$ that satisfies $N=\bigcup_{n\in N}[n]$ then it is immediate that $gng^{-1}\in N$ for every $n\in N$ and $g\in G$, so the conclusion that $N$ is a normal subgroup is justified.

Comment: in your definition of normal subgroup you write $gng^{-1}$ gor every g$\in $N .i think it is not 'N' but 'G'.please check it out...

Comment: Elegant proof +1

Comment: @CloudJR Thank you. You are right. I repaired now.

Comment: How will apply this result, to determine a subgroup of given order is normal, if the class equation of the group is given

Answer (score 1):

A subset $Y$ of a set $X$ with a $G$ action is [invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Invariant_subsets) if and only if it is a union of orbits. Here $X=G$, the action is $g \cdot h : = g h g^{-1}$. Btw, there is another action of $G\times G$ on $G$,

$$(g_1, g_2) \cdot g = g_1 g g_2^{-1}$$