# Artin exercise 2.5.4: Let $f:\Bbb R^+\to\Bbb C^\times$ be the map $f(x)=e^{ix}$. Prove that $f$ is a homomorphism, and determine its kernel and image.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, group-homomorphism

I am trying to solve:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{+} \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ be the map $f(x) = e^{ix}$. Prove that $f$ is a homomorphism, and determine its kernel and image.

Here is my attempt.

> Given $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, we have
> \begin{align*}
> f(x+y) = e^{i(x+y)} = e^{ix + iy} = e^{ix} e^{iy} = f(x) f(y),
> \end{align*}
> so $f$ is a homomorphism. I claim that $\mathrm{ker}(\varphi) = \{2\pi k \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Indeed, we have:
> \begin{align*}
> x \in \mathrm{ker}(f) & \iff f(x) = 1 \\
> & \iff e^{ix} = 1 \\
> & \iff \cos(x) + i \sin x = 1 \\
> & \iff \cos x = 1, \; \sin x = 0 \\
> & \iff x = 2\pi k, \; k \in \mathbb{Z}
> \end{align*}
> Finally, I claim that $\mathrm{Im}(f) = S^1 = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| = 1\}$. We have:
> \begin{align*}
> z \in \mathrm{Im}(f) & \iff \exists x \in \mathbb{R}, \; f(x) = e^{ix} = z \\
> & \iff |z| = 1 \\
> & \iff z \in S^1 
> \end{align*}

How does this look?

Comment: Pretty good, but the definition of $S^1$ needs an equal sign, not a less than.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it.

Comment: This works well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's good work. Well done!

You've explained things clearly & formally and reached the correct conclusions.

Some might say that relying too much on the symbol "$\iff$" is bad form, but I disagree, along with many others.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, thank you very much. I originally proved the inclusions separately but saw $\iff$ as the "more rigorous approach." It's very good to know that there are different opinions on this.

Comment: You're welcome, @user861776. I didn't know about this view until I read [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2175828/a-normal-subgroup-is-the-union-of-conjugacy-classes?r=SearchResults#comment4475532_2175828).