# for $n\ge3$, every nontrivial normal subgroup of $S_n$ either contains a $3$-cycle or a product of two disjoint $2$-cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

**Prove that for $n\ge3$, every nontrivial normal subgroup of $S_n$ either contains a $3$-cycle or a product of two disjoint $2$-cycles.**

This question cannot directly use the advanced fact that $A_n$ is simple group for $n\ge5$ and classification of normal subgroup of $S_n$ ($n\ge 3$) like [here](https://planetmath.org/normalsubgroupsofthesymmetricgroups).

My attempts:

A normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ is union of conjugacy classes, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2175840/481713).  The [conjugacy class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class) of $S_n$ should have same cycle type, [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Conjugacy_Classes_of_Symmetric_Group).

Conjugacy class itself is not closed in group multiplication. I want to prove that a normal subgroup generated by any conjugacy class of $S_n$ will contain a $3$-cycle or a product of two disjoint $2$-cycles.

That is to construct a $3$-cycle or a product of two disjoint $2$-cycles just by multiplying group element with same cycle type. However I don't have idea how to proceed, or is there other easy way to prove original problem?

Comment: A normal subgroup that contains a transposition contains all transposition, and hence equals $S_n$. So you may assume it does not contain any transposition.  Now mimic the usual proof that any nontrivial normal subgroup of $A_n$ contains a $3$-cycle.