# Finding the number of normal subgroups of this group which has order 21

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

This question was asked in my abstract algebra quiz and I was unable to solve it.

> How many normal subgroups does a non-abelian G of order 21 have other than identity {e} and G ?

Here 7>3 and 6|3 so there are two groups and one is $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$ and other is non-abelian generated by c,d such that |c|=3 and |d|=7 ... .

But I don't want to use the result for non-abelian groups that  c,d such that |c|=3 and |d|=7 ... . and couldn't think of any result which I can use , so can you please help me with this question.

Comment: You mean $3|6$ ("$3$ divides $6$"), not $6|3$.

Comment: What "result for non-abelian groups that $c$, $d$ such that $|c|=3$ and $|d|=7$" do you mean and don't want to use?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/819180/how-many-normal-subgroups-does-a-non-abelian-group-g-of-order-21?rq=1).

Comment: The non-abelian group you are considering has the group representation $$G=\langle x, y : x^7=y^3=e, yx=x^2y\rangle.$$ Using Sylow theorems, $G$ has exactly one Sylow $7$-subgroup, $P_7=\langle x : x^7=e\rangle$ which is normal. Also it has $7$ Sylow $3$-subgroups, none of which are normal.